# how to debug AngularJs and NodeJs code in Visual Studio Code

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, visual-studio-code, angular-services

i need some help from you guys i am new in AngularJs,i want debug my code in Visual Studio code how do this please help me, i was installed Debugger for Chrome but its shows

> breakpoints ignored because generated code not found

when i switch option Attach to Chrome, with sourcemaps Application does not start its show belo error,

> Cannot connect to runtime process, timeout after 10000 ms - (reason:
>   Cannot connect to the target: undefined).

when i select Launch Chrome against localhost, with sourcemaps option my application run perfectly but debugger does not run

how to solve this type of problem,

```
 {
        "version": "0.2.0",
        "configurations": [
            {
                "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost, with sourcemaps",
                "type": "chrome",
                "request": "launch",
                "url": "http://localhost:8080",
                "sourceMaps": true,
                "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}"
            },
            {
                "name": "Attach to Chrome, with sourcemaps",
                "type": "chrome",
                "request": "attach",
                  "url": "http://localhost:8080",
                "port":8080,
                "sourceMaps": true,
                "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}"
            }
        ]
    }
```

[image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is because you need to launch Chrome with remote debugging enabled by changing the launch parameters to --remote-debugging-port=9222. You'd then need to change your port for the Attach to Chrome config to 9222.